# return to first function() at the end of last function()

Tags: python, function

If you scroll to the bottom of below; I am trying to return to the first function at the end of my *last* function using     `process_records()`
. My attempt returns `Undefined variable 'process_records'pylint(undefined-variable)`

```
def process_records(self, records, map_data, completed=None, errors=None):
    """Code to execute after webdriver initialization."""
    series_not_null = False
    try:
        num_attempt = 0

        for record in records.itertuples(): # not working
            print(record)
            series_not_null = True

            self.navigate_to_search(num_attempt)
            self.navigate_to_member(mrn)
            self.navigate_to_assessment()
            self.add_assessment(record, map_data)
            self.driver.switch_to.parent_frame() # not working
            sleep(.5)

    except Exception as exc:
        if series_not_null:
            errors = self.process_series_error(exc)

    return completed, errors

def navigate_to_search(self, num_attempt):
    """Uses webdriver to navigate to Search tab and select Member Status=All"""

    if num_attempt == 0:
        page_change_until(self.driver, By.XPATH, './/*[text()="Search"]')
        wait_ready_state(self.driver)
    else:
        self.driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
        elem = wait_until(self.driver, By.XPATH, './/*[text()="Search"]')
        is_disp_n = 0
        while True:
            if elem.is_displayed():
                break
            else:
                self.driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
                is_disp_n += 1
                sleep(1)
            if is_disp_n == 20:
                raise Exception('Could not find Search tab after 20 tries.')

    num_attempt += 1
    radio_locator = (By.XPATH, './/*[@type="RADIO"][@value="All"]')

    while True:
        break_while_timer = datetime.now()

        if datetime.now() - break_while_timer > timedelta(seconds=20):
            break_while = True
            break

        try:
            if wait_until(self.driver, *radio_locator).is_selected():
                pass
            else:
                wait_until(self.driver, *radio_locator).click()
            break
        except Exception:
            sleep(1)

def navigate_to_member(self, mrn):
    """Finds member"""
    wait_until(self.driver, By.XPATH, './/*[@name="MemberIdItem_1"]').clear()
    wait_until(self.driver, By.XPATH, './/*[@name="MemberIdItem_1"]').send_keys(f'{mrn}'+Keys.ENTER)

    page_change_until(self.driver, By.XPATH, f'.//*[text()="{mrn}"]')

    wait_ready_state(self.driver)

def navigate_to_assessment(self):
    """Navigates to the appropriate contact log"""
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[eventproxy^='memberAssessment']").click() #clicks assessment icon
    element = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[contains(text(), '{self.assessment_type}')]")
    actions = ActionChains(self.driver)
    actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//div[contains(text(), '{self.assessment_type}')]").click()
    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[eventproxy^='createSelectedAssessmentsButton']").click()


def add_assessment(self, record, map_data):
    """Create contact log"""
    qna_frame = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[id^='iccc']")
    self.driver.switch_to.frame(qna_frame)

    pages = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul[class='nav nav-pills nav-stacked qna-tabs']")
    pages = pages.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")

    for page in pages:
        page.click()

        # for record in records.itertuples(): #attempt

        questions = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("fieldset")
        questions = [question for question in questions if question.text not in  ("", " ", None)]

        for question in questions[1:]:
            q_text = question.find_element_by_css_selector("span[class='question-text ng-binding']").text
            questionType = map_data.loc[map_data['question_text'] == q_text, 'question_type'].item()
            answer = map_data.loc[map_data['question_text'] == q_text, 'map'].item()
            answer = getattr(record, answer)

            if answer not in ("", " ", "NaT", "NaN", None):

                if questionType == 'checks':
                    self.choose_checks(question, answer)
                else:
                    try:
                        if questionType == 'text':
                            self.driver.implicitly_wait(0)

                            (question.find_element_by_css_selector("textarea").send_keys(str(answer))
                            if 
                                question.find_elements_by_css_selector("textarea")
                            else 
                                question.find_element_by_css_selector("input").send_keys(answer))

                            self.driver.implicitly_wait(15)

                        elif questionType == 'date':
                            try:
                                answer = answer.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
                                question.find_element_by_css_selector("input").send_keys(answer)
                                # page.click()

                            except Exception as e:
                                raise Errors.RequiredDataError('Issues with Assessment Date -- {}'.format(e))
                        elif questionType == 'radio':
                            question.find_element_by_css_selector("input[value='{}']".format(answer)).click()
                    except:
                        continue                              
                    else:
                        pass

    self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#publishButton").click()
    sleep(3)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-mini.btn-primary"))).click()
    process_records()
```

I have also tried:

```
self.process_records()
```

Answer (score 2):

This whole code-block seems to be inside a class. So you should be using `self.process_records()` to call the function.

The `process_records` method expects a few positional arguments (apart from self) - you'll probably need to pass those to the function too.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that; as you can see in my OP. It says "no value for argument in method call"

Comment: As I said, you're calling a method which expects 2 mandatory arguments (record, map_data) apart from the `self` argument. So your call should look something like `self.process_records(record, map_data)`

Comment: Ah, you are so wise.